# Is there any visual attack network flow monitoring tools?

Tags: networking

What's the flow attack monitoring tools?

in this [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Re7eSmjFgV4), 
after the author's back, in the PC screen, there is a running software, showing the world network's attack traffic.

[image]

is there really have this type software for monitor the world's attack network traffic?

Comment: Do you want to see all of "world's network traffic"? Or do you want to see "attacks" network traffic only?

Comment: oh, the `attack` network traffic.

Comment: Where do you get this data from? Many attacks occur over secured connections, which mean you can not detect them even if you have installed network-sniffing equipment in all countries of the world. Or do you want a service that gives you this data too?

Comment: why [Norse](http://www.norse-corp.com) can realize this?

Comment: They can not. They just show the few attacks that their "*world's largest dedicated threat intelligence network*" can see, which is probably like 1% of all attacks that occur, and 0% of the sophisticated ones.